# How do I execute the function exactly like it was executed inside the third party library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webrtc

How can I execute the OK.sendToAll(...) from span exactly if it was executed from Section - Perfect?

OK is actually SimpleOKRTC third party library, if I execute it inside that videoAdded section then it works correctly but when I am trying to execute it from  its not doing correct

Any idea please?

```
<span onclick="func_OK();">TEST</span>

<script src="/js/blatest_third_party_SimpleOKRTC_for_example.js"></script>
<script>
var OK = new SimpleOKRTC({
  autoRequestMedia: true,
  detectSpeakingEvents: true,
});

// Section - Perfect
OK.on('videoAdded', function (video, peer) {  
  OK.sendToAll("bla bla"); // works
});    

// But now 
function func_OK() {
  OK.sendToAll("bla bla"); // does not work same way like 'videoAdded'
}
</script>
```

Comment: *"does not work same way like 'videoAdded'"* How did it work before? What's different?

Comment: Since the "one that works" is called inside a callback, I'd think it was related to data/functionality being ready at that point that makes it work.

Comment: inside a callback it works but i need that same inside callback to be executed form <span>